# Should a Skeleton loading effect be used when refreshing a view with data already present?

Tags: android, ios, loading, frontend-development

I'm developing a mobile app, should I display a skeleton effect when the user trigger a pull refresh even when there's already a data on the screen and won't load a new or additional data in those specific component?

I know it might be better to avoid it in this specific scenario, and I don't see any sense of adding a skeleton effect to display a loading since a pull refresh already indicate that there's already a loading happening in the background, but I can't find a solid reference for it to prove that this is not a good practice.

If I should not use the skeleton effect for that scenario, can anyone gave me a reference to prove it?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you call a *shimmer effect*? To me shimmer is a sound effect, never heard it before in relation with UX or UI

Comment: @Devin you can search it on google images, its another visual representation of activity indicator

Comment: @Devin I think it's that effect you see in mobile UI's where gray outlines of content are shown and slightly "shimmering" to indicate that it's being loaded. I've personally never heard of "shimmer" to mean sound.

Comment: ah I found it, for me it always was a skeleton, I learned something new, thank you!

@Parrotmaster in sound, shimmer is a type of reverb effect where the reverberation takes the higher frequencies and create a lush pad in the background, see https://youtu.be/jtFmV6fio54?si=NLresoOYgX7n1Zm9&t=679 (I use this same pedal but can't post photos, hence the video haha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already show that loading is happening (pull down a load spinner and it spins as content is loading), then you don't show an extra effect. Especially when you already have data on the screen.

Think of it this way: if the loading takes a while, all you've done is take the content away from the user and they have no real content to look at while they wait.

I prefer shimmering to occur when there wasn't any content to begin with and you don't want to show an empty page.

Comment: +1. A spinner communicates that something's being refreshed, without destroying what the user was looking at.